# FTP file transfer interrupted

Tags: socket.io, ftpwebrequest

When I am trying to upload file through my own ftp client application to FTP server , sometimes I am able to upload 20 GB file but sometimes I am getting following error:-

**System.IO.Exception: Unable to write data to transport connection:-> An existing connection was forcibly closed by remote host
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException:An existing connection was forcibly closed by remote host
at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[]buffer, Int32 offset,Int32 size, SocketFlags  socketFlags)
at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Write(Byte[]buffer, Int32 offset,Int32 size)**

Is this problem of FTP application or router which is breaking this connection?